# The type arguments for method... cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#

The code looks as following:

```
private IQueryable<TSearchResultItem> Search(bool flag)
{
    var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Index);
    var ctx = index.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck);
    var items = ctx.GetQueryable<TSearchResultItem>();

    var search = HttpContext.Current.Request[SearchTxtParameter];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<LookbookSearchResultItem>();
        predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Contributors != null);
        return items.Filter(predicate);
    }
    return items;
}
```

The issue is in this line:

```
return items.Filter(predicate);
```

The error:

```
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'QueryableExtensions.Filter<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

How to overcome it?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Excuse me. I've update the post with error message.

Comment: What is the relationship between TSearchResultItem and LookbookSearchResultItem?

Comment: public class LookbookSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem

Comment: Is `TSearchResultItem` a generic type parameter? This won't typecheck since `LookbookSearchResultItem` is not a `TSearchResultItem`. If you manually apply the type parameter to the call to `Filter` you should get another error explaining the problem.

Comment: public abstract class SearchControllerBase<TSearchResultItem> : ODataController where TSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the predicate you're passing to the `Filter` extension method expects a `TSource` (i.e. `LookbookSearchResultItem`)  that is different from the `TSource` (i.e. `TSearchResultItem`) expected by the `Filter` method.

Since you haven't explicitly specified the required type for the `Filter` method, the compiler is therefore confused which type to consider `TSearchResultItem` or `LookbookSearchResultItem` and that's why you're getting this error.